# Is it possible to Breed an Animal to have more Females than Males?

Tags: natural-selection, pregnancy, gender

Minute Earth talked about environmental factors that cause animals and humans to have more male or female children: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IaYhG11ckA

Presuming that is accurate, I was wondering if you could artificially select for people or animals who have more children of a certain gender?

As far as I know, there are no animals that do produce notably more males than females, or vice versa, except maybe some insects.

Comment: Presuming that is accurate, I was wondering if you could artificially select for people or animals who have more children of a certain gender? As far as I know, there are no animals that do produce notably more males than females, or vice versa, except maybe some insects. natural-selection pregnancy gender

Comment: I guess this answer is accidental?

Comment: Do you have some limiting criteria for "animal". Various animals have different influences in sex determination, and some have factors that are easier to adjust than others (e.g. some amphibians and reptiles will have an entire nest of eggs result in one gender based on temperature, which isn't an influence for mammals).

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein The question is related to a fictional race of reptiles (snake based), so that's pretty relevant. It's a story about the Naga, said to be spirits of rivers and snakes (like a centaur or mermaid, upper body human, lower body snake). I also wanted to learn about the subject in general, as I was taught that all creatures have a 50/50 split in gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**
 What you are looking for is a meiotic drive, it's a genetic factor that favors its own transmission. Sex linkage is very common in these due to sex chromosomes not undergoing recombination. Once such driver, [R2D2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26882987) (I shit you not) is a Y linked gene that drastically increases the number of male offspring in a mouse that carries it, to the point it can cause a population collapse from lack of females. 
[Several](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/2008/05/battle-of-the-sexes/#.WVENQ2jyvIU) such drives are known, none quite as drastic as R2D2.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you, I never heard of this. If I may ask, is there any comparable gene known of in the human genome?

Comment: I don't know of any sex linked ones in humans, but there are a few other kind. https://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v31/n3/abs/ng910.html